# .gitignore does not work for subfolder of ignored folder

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php, gitignore

I'm using Laravel and the Github program for subversions. In my .gitignore file i type:

`/vendor`

My project structure looks like this:

```
Root
 app
 bootstrap
 public
 vendor
```

And it's all the files in vendor i want to ignore in git. Most of the files works to ignore there with typing /vendor in my .gitignore, but some files don't.

The files that doesn't work are `autoload.php - vendor/autoload.php`

And files in `vendor/composer` - like:

```
autoload_classmap.php
autoload_namespaces.php
autoload_real.php
ClassLoader.php
installed.json
```

What am i doing wrong in my .gitignore file?

Comment: Could you please check if `vendor/autoload.php` and the files in `vendor/comoser` have already tracked in the repository? A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally **untracked** files that Git should ignore. It has no effect on the files already tracked.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After adding vendor folder in gitignore did you clear the git cache

```
git rm -r --cached vendor

git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore"
```

This will remove vendor folder completely.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I got the problem. I don't know how but my `.gitignore` file pushes it self in a directory called `.gitignore` I just deleted that directory and copied the content of the file in the root of the git project and updated it. Worked for me. Just consider this: file `.gitignore` should be in the root directory of the repo.